# Merging cells in phpexcel without losing data

Tags: phpexcel, symfony-2.3

I'm working on symfony with phpexcel, i have some merged cells from B1 to E1 like this :

```
$phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B2:B5')
```

And i'm setting data in each cell from B2 to B5, but when i generate excel file i only find data in B2 cell but others are lost, any suggestions?

Comment: So what do you expect to happen when you merge cells? What happens when you merge cells in MS Excel? Why do you expect PHPExcel to behave any differently to MS Excel?

Answer (score 1):

That's because your merging. Try to add all data in B2 cell and then merge.